# Cartesian (outer) product of lists in OCaml

Tags: list, polymorphism, tuples, ocaml

I would like to iterate over all combinations of elements from a list of lists which have the same length but not necessarily the same type. This is like the cartesian product of two lists (which is easy to do in OCaml), but for an arbitrary number of lists.

First I tried to write a general cartesian (outer) product function which takes a list of lists and returns a list of tuples, but that can't work because the input list of lists would not have elements of the same type.

Now I'm down to a function of the type

```
'a list * 'b list * 'c list -> ('a * 'b * 'c) list
```

which unfortunately fixes the number of inputs to three (for example). It's

```
let outer3 (l1, l2, l3) =
   let open List in
   l1 |> map (fun e1 -> 
       l2 |> map (fun e2 ->
           l3 |> map (fun e3 ->
               (e1,e2,e3))))
   |> concat |> concat
```

This works but it's cumbersome since it has to be redone for each number of inputs. Is there a better way to do this?

Background: I want to feed the resulting flat list to `Parmap.pariter`.

Comment: I'm not sure you can do this for arbitrary types. The type polymorphism is first-order i.e. for any 'a, 'b, 'c ... whilst you want a second-order polymorphism i.e. for any set of types 'a1...'an. But my OCaml is very out of date.

Comment: hmm... as far as I understand cartesian product requires two sets and should have type `'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list`. Of course, as any other products you can chain them.

Comment: ok, one could start with two input lists and try to do it recursively. however i don't see precisely how: if i do it once i get an `'a * 'b list`. now i want to do it again, chaining with a `'c list`. but then i get a `(('a * 'b) * 'c) list`. now the problem is how to flatten nested tuples in a polymorphic way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To solve your task for arbitrary ntuple we need to use existential types. We can use GADT, but they are close by default. Of course we can use open variants, but I prefer a little more syntactically heavy but more portable solution with first class modules (and it works because GADT can be [expressed](http://okmij.org/ftp/ML/first-class-modules/first-class-modules.pdf) via first class modules). But enough theory, first of all we need a function that will produce the `n_cartesian_product` for us, with type `'a list list -> 'a list list`

```
let rec n_cartesian_product = function
  | [] -> [[]]
  | x :: xs ->
    let rest = n_cartesian_product xs in
    List.concat (List.map (fun i -> List.map (fun rs -> i :: rs) rest) x)
```

Now we need to fit different types into one type `'a`, and here comes existential types, let's define a signature:

```
module type T = sig
  type t
  val x : t
end
```

Now let's try to write a lifter to this existential:

```
let int x  = (module struct type t = int let x = x end : T)
```

it has type:

```
int -> (module T)
```

Let's extend the example with few more cases:

```
let string x = (module struct type t = string let x = x end : T)
let char x = (module struct type t = char let x = x end : T)

let xxs = [
  List.map int [1;2;3;4];
  List.map string ["1"; "2"; "3"; "4"];
  List.map char ['1'; '2'; '3'; '4']
]

# n_cartesian_product xxs;;
- : (module T) list list =
[[<module>; <module>; <module>]; [<module>; <module>; <module>];
 [<module>; <module>; <module>]; [<module>; <module>; <module>];
 ...
```

Instead of first class modules you can use other abstractions, like objects or functions, if your type requirements allow this (e.g., if you do not need to expose the type `t`). Of course, our existential is very terse, and maybe you will need to extend the signature.

Comment: ah, now I've got the question. I'll update the answer. It is possible in OCaml...

Comment: ok thanks for the update. wow, that's much more work than i had expected. but i guess it's what's needed to trick the type system. now what remains to do, is to adapt my original function to be iterated over the flat list, in order to unwrap the values again. but i guess i can look the details up in the first-class modules docs.

Comment: is it correct that when i know that there is a small number of actual possible types, i could do the same thing much more concisely with GADTs? (only one wrapper function?)

Comment: yes, exactly. If your type is close, just use GADT (and even if it is open, you still can use GADT, but in that case you need 4.02.+)

Comment: hmm, i tried GADTs that but didn't succeed yet. let's say i have only `int` and `float`. then i need to coerce them into one type so i can use `n_cartesian_product`. for that i first tried to use `type _ t = | I: int -> int t | F: float -> float t`. but this does not give a homogeneous input list. so then i use `type tt = |I: int -> tt|F: float ->tt`. this allows me to hide the different types, and i can use `n_cartesian_product`. then i can later try to pattern match on the generated combinations. but how is a GADT even useful here?

Comment: also, it seems that one wrapper function is not enough, i would still need one for each type i want to wrap it seems. maybe one unwrapper function is ok...

Comment: This answer is driving me back to Clojure (where `for` is all you'd need, fwiw).  :-)   I mean, I have deep respect for OCaml's type system, and I understand that there are all sorts of corners that lisps can cut with dynamic types (at a cost, of course), but I would have thought that a cross product was such a common use case that OCaml would have a built in function for it for lists of any type.

Comment: I just found `Core.Std.List.cartesian_product` and `Batteries.List.cartesian_product` (which only handle two lists, so aren't an answer to OP's question).  That is satisfying enough for me--no need for me to run away from OCaml.

Comment: @user3240588 Thanks--not a bad idea for newbies like me.

Answer (score 3):

I used @ivg 's answer but in a version with a GADT. I reproduce it here for reference. In a simple case where only the types `float` and `int` can appear in the input lists, first set

```
type wrapped = Int : int -> wrapped | Float : float -> wrapped
```

this is a GADT without type parameter. Then

```
let wrap_f f = Float f
let wrap_i i = Int f
```

wrap types into the sum type. On `wrapped` value lists we can call `n_cartesian_product` from @ivg 's answer. The result is a list `combinations: wrapped list list` which is flat (for the present purposes).

Now to use `Parmap`, i have e.g. a worker function `work : float * int * float * float -> float`. To get the arguments out of the wrappers, I pattern match:

```
combinations |> List.map (function 
 | [Float f1; Int i; Float f2; Float f3] -> (f1, i, f2, f3)
 | _ -> raise Invalid_argument "wrong parameter number or types")
```

to construct the flat list of tuples. This can be finally fed to `Parmap.pariter` with the worker function `work`.

This setup is almost the same as using a regular sum type `type wrapsum = F of float | I of int` instead of `wrapped`. The pattern matching would be the same; the only difference seems to be that getting a wrong input, e.g. `(F 1, I 1, F 2.0, F, 3.0)` would be detected only at runtime, not compile time as here.

Comment: One thing that is still not pretty is that i pattern match on a list in the end, with a catch-all case, instead of a tuple. Not sure if it's possible to avoid that.